# mySQL Update based on Multi Column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am trying to sync up. The original table needs to be updated based on the values from the repl table if the values have changed. When I run the update by joining the tables it updates all join rows with the first value.

```
UPDATE orig inner join repl on ((orig.lookuptype =  repl.lookuptype) AND (orig.lookupsubtype = repl.lookupsubtype)) SET orig.choicevalue = repl.choicevalue, orig.choicelabel = repl.choicelabel, orig.isactive = repl.isactive where orig.choicevalue <> repl.choicevalue OR orig.choicelabel <> repl.choicelabel OR   orig.isactive <> repl.isactive
```

or

```
UPDATE orig INNER JOIN repl USING (lookupsubtype,lookupsubtype) SET orig.choicevalue = repl.choicevalue,orig.choicelabel = repl.choicelabel, orig.isactive = repl.isactive where orig.choicevalue <> repl.choicevalue OR orig.choicelabel <> repl.choicelabel OR    orig.isactive <> repl.isactive
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orig` ( `lookupid` int(11) NOT NULL, `lookuptype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `lookupsubtype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `choicevalue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `choicelabel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `isactive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL )
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is better if you give the structure of your 2 tables too

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orig` (
  `lookupid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lookuptype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lookupsubtype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `choicevalue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `choicelabel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isactive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
)

Comment: @Begueradj Your [attempted edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6074144) left out the backtick characters surrounding the table/field names.

Comment: At this point, you are better off setting up triggers instead of trying to do a manual sync.

Comment: I cannot set triggers on the table. Any other options?